# How do i select just one expanded panel in Vuejs (vuetify) using the index?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

i am using Vuetify in my Vue.js project and i have a problem with the expanded panels. I am doing a v-for over an array of objects and then i am putting the expanded panels with external control. External control means a button separated from the panel that expand the panel and closes it.

my code at the moment is this:

```
     <v-btn @click="showHidePanel(index)">
        Button
      </v-btn>
      <v-expansion-panels v-model="panel>
        <v-expansion-panel>
          <v-expansion-panel-content>
            I am expanded!
          </v-expansion-panel-content>
        </v-expansion-panel>
      </v-expansion-panels>
```

And now my script:

```
data() {
  return {
     panel: [],
  }
}



//
showHidePanel(data) {
  if (this.panel.length == 0) {
    this.panel = [...Array(data).keys()].map((k, i) => i);
  } else {
    this.panel = [];
  }
},
```

As the 'panel' variable is an array, all panels are expanding but i have tried with an integer and it doesnt worked too.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've copied your `showHidePanel` function from the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels#external-control).  That function is designed to toggle all or none of the panels.  To toggle just the panel at `index` use:

```
showHidePanel(index) {
  if (this.panel.indexOf(index)) {
    this.panel = this.panel.filter(i => i!=index);
  } else {
    this.panel.push(index);
  }
},
```

Comment: No, `this.panel` should be initialized as an empty array.

Comment: Didn´t worked... when it enters of the first if the array is empty

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Do you want all the panel open at the start?